# Custom Post with Products

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

i am trying to get all details of my custom post and print selected data from that on my single-product page.

so lets say the custom post is named Games and the product page is the one were you select on of the games to buy.

i am using:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'games',
    )
);
$review_details = new WP_Query($args);
```

this is getting me most of the information the product instance, although i chose the post type to be games. since in the post i have the age and rating for the games.

How will I be able to get all the details i already have in the Games Post to the single-product page of a game i am selling?

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'reviews',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'games_books', // name of custom field
        'value' => '"' . $game_id . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
));
$review_details = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($review_details);
```

and when i use print_r($review_details); all the parameters of reviews are empty, but when i do the same from a post then i can get the reviews.
again i need to print this data on the single-product page

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: how will i be able to print all the details of the customPost Games on the single Product page of that specific game

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have additional meta information for the Custom Post Type 'games'. Outputting this extra information can be done using either:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'key');
```

See here for more information https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

---

Or if you're using a common custom field plugin, like ACF, you'll need to use get_field()

```
get_field('key', $post_id);
```

See here for more info https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: i am not being able to access the fields, any assumptions why?

Comment: If you could provide the full code in your template for your current attempt, that may tell us more.

Comment: i hope this part of the code is enough and clears the issue, i appreciate your help, or attempt

Comment: Is the value of the 'games_books' meta field actually "123", including the quotation marks?

If you want to compare exact values it's best to use a compare value of '=' instead of 'LIKE'.

Answer (score 0):

To print a data for custom post, you can use WP_Query with While Option.

For example:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'games');
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<!-- Loop Start -->
<?php the_title(); ?>
<!-- Loop End -->

<?php else: endif; ?>
```

If you want to print custom areas

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true); ?>
```

Comment: i already have this done to print, i am printing the posts after all, what i want is to print the information from the posts on the single product page. What is happening is i am getting all tags with empty values, its like i have no access on the posts when i am in a single product page.

Comment: If you want a start new query, you should close the before query. After that you can start a new args and new query like your first message. To do that, before the new query, use that. <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>